# Bounding expectation of an expression given a tail bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, moment-generating-functions, distribution-tails

Let $X$ be a positive (i.e. nonzero) random variable which is bounded in probability as follows: there ex. constants $A, C > 0$ s.t. for every $\varepsilon > 0$
$$ \mathbb{P}(X \geq \varepsilon) \leq A \exp (-C \varepsilon^2) $$

Knowing this, is there anything we can say about the expression $ \mathbb{E} [ \exp (-1/X) ]$? I feel like intuitively this should mean we can somehow bound this expression as well, at least in probability, but I can't figure out how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated, I don't even really know where to start on this one.

---

Edit: the sub-gaussian tail bound on $X$ does lead to equivalent properties for $X$, but since I have the reciprocal here, I don't really know much about it... it isn't sub-gaussian itself as far as I know, so I can't apply any results for the moment-generating function here...

Comment: What if $X$ is a negative r.v.?

Comment: @geetha290krm Fair point, I should mention that in this case it is positive. Edited to reflect this

Comment: For a non-negative random variable $Y$, we have $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y > \lambda) d\lambda$. I think the tail bound you a lower bound for the expectation you are trying to estimate.

Comment: @Julius A lower bound would be a bit unfortunate, as I am trying to bound it above if possible... but you're saying this isn't possible with just the given information?

Comment: @LSK21 Apologies, I missed a sign swap in an inequality. You should be able to get an upper bound on the expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that, for non-negative random variables $Y$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y > \lambda) \, d\lambda$$
(this is a consequence of Fubini's theorem). Applying this to $Y = \exp(-1/X)$, which is supported on $[0,1]$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(-1/X)] &= \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(\exp(-1/X) > \lambda )\, d\lambda \\
&= \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X > -1/\ln(\lambda)) \, d \lambda\\
&\leq \int_0^1 A \exp(-C/(\ln(\lambda))^2) \, d\lambda.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is $Y$ only supported on $(0, 1]$? The function $f(x) = \exp(-1/x)$ takes non-zero values outside of this interval...

Comment: @LSK21 The support of a real-valued random variable $Y$ is the smallest closed subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ for which $ Y \in A$ almost-surely.

Comment: Yes, I know, but Y can take values outside of $(0,1]$ with positive probability, can it not? I feel like I am just overlooking something...

Comment: @LSK21 Under the assumption that $X$ is a positive random variable, $Y = f(X)$ only takes values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh true, turns out I was missing something obvious after all, thanks!